# Indent R Markdown code block in PDF/LaTeX output

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr

I am currently writing a document in RMarkdown and knitting the output to pdf. It would be desirable for me to indent the code blocks to be consistent with the rest of my formatting.

Here is the document as written:

[image: example document]

I would like the gray portion of the block to be in line with "This is a sentence."

Is there a way to do this in R markdown, perhaps by dropping down into LaTeX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the formatting of the box, the key line in the LaTeX template is:

```
\newenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{snugshade}}{\end{snugshade}}
```

The `snugshade` command is defined within the `framed` [LaTeX package](https://ctan.org/pkg/framed?lang=en), which is useful for creating shaded boxes as included within RMarkdown. However, it lacks many controls to simply edit the styling.

Based off [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33983/how-to-eliminate-the-horizontal-spacing-of-the-frame-in-the-framed-package), you could consider using the `mdframed` package which offers more advanced controls than the `framed` package. As explained [here](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf) The margins can be tweaked using the `renewenvironment` command, which we will use to redefine the `Shaded` function with our custom style:

[image]

To get this working in RMarkdown, we need to replace the `Shaded` environment with our new definition. This can be achieved as follows:

````
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: TRUE
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{mdframed}
  - \definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{.95}
  - \renewenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{mdframed}[
      backgroundcolor=shadecolor,
      linecolor = shadecolor,
      leftmargin=\dimexpr\leftmargin-2pt\relax,
      innerleftmargin=1.6pt,
      innertopmargin=5pt,
      skipabove=10pt,skipbelow=3pt
    ]}{\end{mdframed}}
---

Some Text

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```
````

[image]

**Note**: as you haven't provided a reproducible example, you will have to fine tune the settings to get this working with your configuration.

> If you start getting more LaTeX commands, you can considering saving this as a separate .tex file as explained [here](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#includes)